# How to rotate a single view controller to landscape in container view controllers?

Tags: ios, rotation, containers, parent-child

My application stack has login screen followed by container view controllers (Parent - Child). I was in a situation to display a single view controller in container view controllers in landscape orientation. I tried creation custom navigation controller and overriding its orientation methods. There is no use since all the container controllers are rotating in landscape. Any help is appreciated.